# Properly handle subitem editing ( or canceling of subitem editing ) in listview with editable subitems

Tags: c++, c, listview, winapi, datagrid

### INTRODUCTION:

I am trying to implement listview control with editable subitems. For in-place editing of items/subitems I use edit control.

I believe that I have managed to properly code placing of the edit control above item/subitem.

### PROBLEM:

I do not know on which events I should end/cancel subitem editing ( hide edit control, set subitem text etc ) and how should I do it.

*To clarify, I speak of the moment when user finishes/cancels in place editing.*

*At this point edit control is no longer needed, so I should hide it ( I do not like recreating it every time; I believe that creating it once and then showing/hiding it when needed is more efficient ).*

I am targeting the behavior **Properties** window has in Visual Studio ( see attached image to see exactly the window I refer to ).

[image]

I want to achieve editing/canceling the same way this window does when user presses ESC key/clicks on another window/clicks on scrollbar etc.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

Using Google, I found few examples but they are old and do not address all of the relevant cases, so that is why I ask here for help.

However, I was able to find out that one of the events I must consider are [`EN_KILLFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), case when user presses <kbd>ESC</kbd>/<kbd>ENTER</kbd> key and the case when user clicks on something other than edit control.

**EDIT:**

I have managed to handle ESC and ENTER keys, as well as the case when user clicks on the another sibling control or switches windows with ALT + TAB. I have updated SSCCE with relevant changes

### QUESTION:

In order to achieve default behavior for a grid ( if there is one for Windows apps ), which messages/events must I handle?

*Can you also point out where should I edit subitem and hide edit control, and where should I just hide edit control?*

**EDIT:**

My only problem remained is to handle the case when user clicks on the listview scrollbars, or on the background of the main window. I just do not know how to handle this and would appreciate all the help I can get.

### RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I use Visual Studio 2013, on Windows 7 x86;

I am developing in C++ using raw WinAPI;

### SSCCE:

Below is the solution I have so far. I have tried to thoroughly comment it, but if more info is required leave a comment and I will update my post.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>   // various listview macros etc
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>      // swprintf_s()

// enable Visual Styles
#pragma comment( linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' \
                         name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
                         processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' \
                         language='*'\"")

// link with Common Controls library
#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib") 

//global variables
HINSTANCE hInst;

// listview subclass procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK ListViewSubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_VSCROLL:
    case WM_HSCROLL:
        // if edit control has the focus take it away and give to listview
        if (GetFocus() == GetDlgItem(GetParent(hwnd), 5000))
            SetFocus(hwnd);  // use WM_NEXTDLGCTL for dialogbox !!!!
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        ::RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ListViewSubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return ::DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// subclass procedure for edit control
LRESULT CALLBACK InPlaceEditControl_SubclassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        return (DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam));
    case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_CHAR:
        //Process this message to avoid message beeps.
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_RETURN:
            return 0L;
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            return 0L;
        default:
            return ::DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_RETURN:
        {
            // get listview handle
            HWND hwndLV = GetDlgItem(GetParent(hwnd), 2000);
            // get edit control's client rectangle
            RECT rc = { 0 };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            // since edit control lies inside item rectangle
            // we can test any coordinate inside edit control's
            // client rectangle
            // I chose ( rc.left, rc.top )
            MapWindowPoints(hwnd, hwndLV, (LPPOINT)&rc, (sizeof(RECT) / sizeof(POINT)));
            // get item and subitem indexes
            LVHITTESTINFO lvhti = { 0 };
            lvhti.pt.x = rc.left;
            lvhti.pt.y = rc.top;
            ListView_SubItemHitTest(hwndLV, &lvhti);
            // get edit control's text
            wchar_t txt[50] = L"";
            Edit_GetText(hwnd, txt, 50);
            // edit cell text
            ListView_SetItemText(hwndLV, lvhti.iItem, lvhti.iSubItem, txt);
            // restore focus to listview
            // this triggers EN_KILLFOCUS
            // which will hide edit control
            SetFocus(hwndLV);
        }
            return 0L;
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            SetFocus(GetDlgItem(GetParent(hwnd), 2000));
            return 0L;
        default:
            return ::DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        ::RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, InPlaceEditControl_SubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }
    return ::DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
// main window procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        //================ create controls
        RECT rec = { 0 };
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rec);

        HWND hwndLV = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW,
            L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | LVS_REPORT, 
            50, 50, 250, 200, hwnd, (HMENU)2000, hInst, 0);
        // in place edit control
        HWND hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_EDIT, L"", ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            200, 265, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)5000, hInst, 0);
        // edit control must have the same font as listview
        HFONT hf = (HFONT)SendMessage(hwndLV, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
        if (hf)
            SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hf, (LPARAM)TRUE);
        // subclass edit control, so we can edit subitem with ENTER, or
        // cancel editing with ESC
        SetWindowSubclass(hwndEdit, InPlaceEditControl_SubclassProc, 0, 0);
        // set extended listview styles
        ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hwndLV, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
        // subclass listview
        SetWindowSubclass(hwndLV, ListViewSubclassProc, 0, 0);

        // add some columns
        LVCOLUMN lvc = { 0 };

        lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
        lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;

        for (long nIndex = 0; nIndex < 5; nIndex++)
        {
            wchar_t txt[50];
            swprintf_s(txt, 50, L"Column %d", nIndex);

            lvc.iSubItem = nIndex;
            lvc.cx = 60;
            lvc.pszText = txt;

            ListView_InsertColumn(hwndLV, nIndex, &lvc);
        }

        // add some items
        LVITEM lvi;

        lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

        for (lvi.iItem = 0; lvi.iItem < 10000; lvi.iItem++)
        {
            for (long nIndex = 0; nIndex < 5; nIndex++)
            {
                wchar_t txt[50];
                swprintf_s(txt, 50, L"Item %d%d", lvi.iItem, nIndex);

                lvi.iSubItem = nIndex;
                lvi.pszText = txt;

                if (!nIndex)  // item 
                    SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, 2000, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&lvi));
                else          // sub-item
                    SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, 2000, LVM_SETITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&lvi));
            }
        }
    }
        return 0L;
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_DBLCLK)  
        {
            switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->idFrom)
            {
            case 2000: // remember, this was our listview's ID
            {
                LPNMITEMACTIVATE lpnmia = (LPNMITEMACTIVATE)lParam;

                // SHIFT/ALT/CTRL/their combination, must not be pressed
                if ((lpnmia->uKeyFlags || 0) == 0)
                {
                    // store item/subitem rectangle
                    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                    // helper values, needed for handling partially visible items
                    int topIndex = ListView_GetTopIndex(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom);
                    int visibleCount = ListView_GetCountPerPage(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom);
                    // if item is vertically partially visible, make it fully visible
                    if ((topIndex + visibleCount) == lpnmia->iItem)
                    {
                        // get the rectangle of the above item -> lpnmia->iItem - 1
                        ListView_GetSubItemRect(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, lpnmia->iItem - 1, lpnmia->iSubItem, LVIR_LABEL, &rc);
                        // ensure clicked item is visible
                        ListView_EnsureVisible(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, lpnmia->iItem, FALSE);
                    }
                    else // item is fully visible, just get its ectangle
                        ListView_GetSubItemRect(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, lpnmia->iItem, lpnmia->iSubItem, LVIR_LABEL, &rc);

                    RECT rcClient = { 0 };  // listview client rectangle, needed if item partially visible
                    GetClientRect(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, &rcClient);
                    // item is horizontally partially visible -> from the right side
                    if (rcClient.right < rc.right)  
                    {
                        // show the whole item
                        ListView_Scroll(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, rc.right - rcClient.right, 0);
                        // adjust rectangle so edit control is properly displayed
                        rc.left -= rc.right - rcClient.right;
                        rc.right = rcClient.right;
                    }
                    // item is horizontally partially visible -> from the left side
                    if (rcClient.left > rc.left)  
                    {
                        // show the whole item
                        ListView_Scroll(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, rc.left - rcClient.left, 0);
                        // adjust rectangle so edit control is properly displayed
                        rc.right += rcClient.left - rc.left;
                        rc.left = rcClient.left;
                    }
                    // it is time to position edit control, we start by getting its window handle
                    HWND hwndEdit = GetDlgItem(hwnd, 5000);
                    //  get item text and set it as edit control's text
                    wchar_t text[51];
                    ListView_GetItemText(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, lpnmia->iItem, lpnmia->iSubItem, text, 50);
                    Edit_SetText(hwndEdit, text);
                    // select entire text
                    Edit_SetSel(hwndEdit, 0, -1);
                    // map listview client rectangle to parent rectangle
                    // so edit control can be properly placed above the item
                    MapWindowPoints(lpnmia->hdr.hwndFrom, hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rc, (sizeof(RECT) / sizeof(POINT)));
                    // move the edit control
                    SetWindowPos(hwndEdit, HWND_TOP, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, 
                        rc.bottom - rc.top, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                    // set focus to our edit control
                    HWND previousWnd = SetFocus(hwndEdit);
                }
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ::DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        return 0L;
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
        return 0L;
    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// WinMain
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    // store hInstance in global variable for later use
    hInst = hInstance;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    // register main window class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Main_Window";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!", 
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return 0;
    }

    // initialize common controls
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex;
    iccex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    iccex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex);

    // create main window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Main_Window", L"Grid control",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 50, 50, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I ran your code, it looks fine except it doesn't handle Esc and Return key for the edit control. You have to subclass the edit control to catch those two keys. Also ListView has its own LabelEdit functions, however ListView default Edit only works for the first column.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Try clicking on the main window and you will see that edit control does not receive `EN_KILLFOCUS`. The same happens when I control listview's scrollbar. It should be hidden in those two cases. I just do not know which event I must process so I can hide the control... Thank you for taking time to try and help. I highly appreciate it. Hopefully my problem will be solved and you and many others will benefit from the solution. Best regards.

Comment: Any updates about the edit control not being subclassed? I'd like to know how you got it to work; I tried subclassing it in the NM_DBLCLK message using SetWindowLong, but the window then freezes and a break point triggers. I'd really love to know how you've done it.

Comment: @user2154149: I have fixed the error you pointed out and added full example code. I hope that the code will help you. Best regards and good luck, if you need further help just let me know.

Comment: Nice, good explanation. But I get the wrong lvhti.iSubItem from ListView_SubItemHitTest (hwndLV, & lvhti), if SubItem is partially invisible. Odd. I think it is better to set iSubItem as the parameter (SetWindowLongPtr) to the edit window, so that it hooks directly to the correct SubItem? I also wonder, why bother hiding the edit window, when it can be destroyed and recreated when needed? Then there is no risk, forget to destroy it? Having two functions, starting and ending editing, would be smooth and I do them. But the last is not the topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

On second thought, the method I posted earlier was wrong. I think it's design error to use `SetCapture` in edit-box like that, it can interfere with bunch of other things. I am going to delete my old answer and pretend nobody saw it!

Your own method is fine with checking for `KILLFOCUS`, you just need subclass for ListView to check scroll messages to mimic `LVN_XXXLABELEDIT`

```
void hideEdit(BOOL save)
{
    //save or not...
    ShowWindow(hedit, SW_HIDE);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK EditProc...
{
    if (msg == WM_KILLFOCUS)
        hideEdit(1);

    if (msg == WM_CHAR)
    {
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE){
            hideEdit(0);
            return 0;
        }
        if (wParam == VK_RETURN){
            hideEdit(1);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(...);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ListProc...
{
    if (msg == WM_VSCROLL || msg == WM_HSCROLL) hideEdit(1);
    return DefSubclassProc(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will study the code and get back to you. Best regards until then.

Comment: ps, you don't need `EN_KILLFOCUS` with this method so remove that. I also added faking mouse click.

Comment: *On second thought, the method I posted earlier was wrong.* I agree, that is why I wanted to find alternative solution, before tampering with yours. *you just need subclass for ListView to check scroll messages* That is only one of many cases, I still need to handle the case when user clicks on the main window's background ( when user clicks on another control it is fine, edit loses focus). If I manage to solve that, I believe this problem will be solved. Thank you for the update.

Comment: Look at Windows Explorer, start editing an item and click the titlebar of parent window, or inactive area of tool bar... the edit control will not close, and nor should it. The requirement you had placed earlier is not right.

Comment: From the *Remarks* section of [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation: *While processing this message, do not make any function calls that display or activate a window. This causes the thread to yield control and can cause the application to stop responding to messages.*  Still, I have managed to solve this problem, and the case when user clicks on scrollbars ( the way you suggested, by handling `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL`). I will update the code from the post soon, now I am trying to handle F12 and TAB...

Comment: Nobody was activating or displaying another window while processing `WM_KILLFOCUS`

Comment: Indeed, it seems I misunderstood *display window* part... Thank you for correcting me. I am currently trying to implement F12 to edit cell, like explorer does, only I will need to adjust it for cell.  I will need some mechanism for looping through cells via keyboard...

Comment: I have decided to abandon F12 and TAB support, so there seems nothing else left to be done. Therefore I am officially accepting your answer, +1 and best regards until next time.