# Use combobox into Listview Items in C++ win32 api

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, combobox

How can I set items of a listview as Combobox in C++ win32 api?

my listview

```
hWndListView = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    WC_LISTVIEW,
    L"",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
    10,
    100,
    430,
    400,
    hWndx,
    (HMENU)IDC_LIST,
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

my combobox

```
HWND hComboBox2 = CreateWindow(
    WC_COMBOBOX,
    CMBX_CLASS_NAME,
    CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE,
    10,
    50,
    300,
    300,
    hWndListView,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

Is it possible?
thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? Maybe you simply want a scrollable are that contains a set of combo box controls ? Maybe you simply want a popup menu too ?

Comment: I'd research third party grid controls, depending on your requirements it'll almost certainly be easier and less stressful than trying to browbeat the listview commctrl into doing what you want.

Comment: thank you for your kind comments. I want to set ListView items with combobox to easily choose values with a limitation. User can choose their item value with combobox. It's really comfortable i thinks.

Comment: I think I did something similar in the past, if I understood you correctly. Perhaps [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251328/properly-handle-subitem-editing-or-canceling-of-subitem-editing-in-listview) can help? Just change hidden edit control to be combobox instead...

Comment: Does anybody have a complete example ? I found this 
 but still no code https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2009123d-a0ce-4438-97ad-b294dc32f458/adding-combo-boxes-to-a-list-view?forum=vcmfcatl

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with standard ListView common control. You can implement your own control that does what you want by subclassing standard one, and letting it do the painting, and all other functionality. Your customization then will include responding to clicks, hittesting to figure out where click happened (with LVM_HITTEST), creating and displaying combobox, and updating item/subitem with new selection from combobox.